# Найти приближённое значение бесконечного произведения по формуле

Tags: c++, ряды

Бесконечное произведение:

.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Необходимо написать код для вычисления конечного произведения, при условии что предел бесконечного множества - N задаётся пользователем. Я не смог понять, как составить саму функцию вычисления бесконечного множества, даже после изучения множества ресурсов по этой теме. Буду очень признателен, если кто поможет.
Формула:

[image: формула]

Comment: Да просто цикл, в цикле вычисляете очередной член — это выражение в произведении и множите на него...

Comment: Уточняю: получается, что надо вычислить выражение 1 - 2 / (n(n + 1) и перемножить его на себя же N раз?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: На первом обороте цикла вычисляете это выражение для n =2, на втором для n=3 и т.д..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держите уже...
Только вот с точностью при вычислениях явно всплывут проблемы.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    double p = 1;
    for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
        p *= 1 - 2./i/(i+1);
    std::cout << p << "\n";
}
```